# Getting testContext out of Method passed to DataProvider

Tags: java, testng

Is it possible to get TextContext out of the Method passed to DataProvider? This is what I mean..

```
@DataProvider(name= "foo")
public static Object[][] testData(Method method){
    TestContext tc = //possible?
    //reason for this, I want to get some property from TextContext
    Object x = tc.getAttribute("bar");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare your `ITestContext` in parameter and TestNG will inject it for you:

```
@DataProvider(name= "foo")
public Object[][] testData(Method method, ITestContext context) {
```